# How to write a defer block with a method returns error

Tags: go

Error handling is not possible when I write a method that returns an error with defer in one-liner.
It will be warned by IDE linter etc.

I write the following code to avoid it.

```golang
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://example.com", nil)
    cli := &http.Client{}
    res, _ := cli.Do(req)

    defer func() {
        _ = res.Body.Close() // catch the error
    }()

    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    log.Println(string(b))
}
```

Comment: And what is your actual question? Note that there is not much you can do about request Close returning an error.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I just want to know how everyone writes when writing a defer with a method returns a error. Because some linter and IDE warn unhandled error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is not the defer, actually its the fact that u are using `res.Body` without checking for whether res.Body == nil

So the part here is missing is the error handling when cli.Do(req) returns an error and nil for res.

You can still do the same differ by adding in a check for the res being nil.
Or you can stop early when cli.Do(req) returns an error

Here is an example https://play.golang.org/p/pnETOjhNCKs

Comment: I wrote the code as an example, so I skipped some error handling.

Comment: Is this an additional issue?
is this a different issue checking `res.Body` from handling error with defer?

Comment: Handling error using defer is not an issue.
Accessing `.Body` from a nil is an issue

Comment: I just want to know how everyone writes when writing a defer with a method returns a error.
Because some linter and IDE warn unhandled error.

Comment: Warning for unhandled error will be regardless of whether you put it in a defer or not.
This warning is just purely based on the fact that the error is not correctly handled.